# Required creepage distance & clearance in high temp. (600~1000℃) for high voltage DC system (400V)

Tags: creepage

We have a high voltage battery pack. During abuse test, the Li-ion cells will eject lots of hot gas and graphite. These ejection will cause short circuit which is definitely not wanted. I want to know what's the required creepage distance & clearance in this circumstance. But the standards and handbook I found only have Room Temp. information. Is there some handbook for high temp. design?

Voltage: 400V max.
Temp.: 600-1000℃

Thanks.

Comment: Creepage is mainly affected by contamination and humidity and not temperature.  Is it <3 mm?  Ionization levels for partial discharge may need more gap.

Comment: We have checked the creepage and clearance according to LV123. It works fine in normal situraton.

Comment: If creepage is mainly affected by contamination and humidity, I believe the graphite ejected during Li-ion cell abuse is the main cause of short circuit. We can focus on this. But will high temp. cause the air easier to be breakdown and thus need a bigger clearance?

Comment: If the cells are already venting their contents, is board creepage distance really a concern? I would have thought that by then, mechanical containment and fire spread control were the only things that mattered.

Comment: Yes, we are preparing some countermeasure to eliminate the venting gas/residue. But we found it is extremely hard to reduce pollution to 0. We are preparing to increase the creepage to a very high value to prevent short circuit.

Comment: Our concern is that do we need to consider the high temp. when we improve our design?  We have some argue internal. Because we don't know if high temp. will make air easier to breakdown.

Comment: Yes FL tubes used electrode heaters about or above those Temperatures to ignite UV gas tubes with phosphor to convert to daylight, to reduce the ignition breakdown voltage requirements for a ballast.